# Linux PREEMPT_RT: SCHED_OTHER performs better than SCHED_FIFO. Why?

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, real-time, raspberry-pi4

I'm experimenting with the realtime capabilities of the Raspberry Pi 3/4.  I've written the following C++ program to test.

```
// Compile with:
// g++ realtime_task.cpp -o realtime_task -lrt && sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+ep realtime_task

#include <cstdio>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
using namespace chrono_literals;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    // allocate this process to the 4th core (core 3)
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(3, &cpuset);
    int result = 0;
    result = sched_setaffinity(pid, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        perror("`sched_setaffinity` failed");
    }

    struct sched_param param;

    // Use SCHED_FIFO
    param.sched_priority = 99;
    result = sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_FIFO, &param);

    // Use SCHED_OTHER
    // param.sched_priority = 0;
    // result = sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_OTHER, &param);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        perror("`sched_setscheduler` failed");
    }

    uint32_t count = 0;
    uint32_t total_loop_time_us = 0;
    uint32_t min_loop_time_us = numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
    uint32_t avg_loop_time_us = 0;
    uint32_t max_loop_time_us = 0;
    
    while(true)
    {
        count++;

        auto start = steady_clock::now();

        auto loop_time_us = duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
        while(loop_time_us < 500)
        { 
            loop_time_us = duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
        }

        min_loop_time_us = min((uint32_t)loop_time_us, (uint32_t)min_loop_time_us);
        total_loop_time_us += loop_time_us;
        avg_loop_time_us = total_loop_time_us / count;
        max_loop_time_us = max((uint32_t)loop_time_us, (uint32_t)max_loop_time_us);

        if ((count % 1000) == 0)
        {
            printf("%u %u %u\r", min_loop_time_us, avg_loop_time_us, max_loop_time_us);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've patched the kernel with the PREEMPT_RT patch.  `uname` reports `5.15.84-v8+ #1613 SMP PREEMPT` and everything runs fine.

Kernel command line arguments have `isolcpus=3 irqaffinity=0-2` to isolate the 4th core (core 3) and reserve it for the program above.  I can see in *htop* that my program is the only process running on the 4th core (core 3).

When using the `SCHED_FIFO` policy, it reports the following minimum, average, and maximum loop times...

```
MIN AVG MAX
500 522 50042
```

.. and *htop* reports:

```
CPU▽ CTXT     PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
  3     1   37238 pi         RT   0  4672  1264  1108 R 97.5  0.0  0:07.57 ./realtime_task
```

When using the `SCHED_OTHER` policy, it reports the following minimum, average, and maximum loop times...

```
MIN AVG MAX
500 500 524
```

.. and *htop* reports:

```
CPU▽ CTXT     PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
  3     0   36065 pi         20   0  4672  1260  1108 R 100.  0.0  1:30.16 ./realtime_task
```

This is the opposite of what I expect.  I expect `SCHED_FIFO` to give me the lower maximum loop time and fewer context switches.  Why am I getting these results?

Comment: Is your program running in an infinite loop on the core, or does it sleep regularly? (i.e. for 1ms every 1s). From what I understand, Linux needs to do some housekeeping on each core (also isolated ones) in the background, so programs need to allow that to happen.

Comment: @sonicwave The program runs in an infinite loop without any sleep.  The housekeeping hypothesis may be right.  If I add a sleep in the inner loop, I do get results similar to SCHED_OTHER, but still slightly worse than what I get with SCHED_OTHER and no sleep.  Still I'd like to better understand that housekeeping.

Comment: I recall we had some issues with the RCU subsystem stalling due to starvation (quick search turns up https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2260151, which mentions the possible cause of having long-running real-time threads). We fixed it by adding a very short sleep to the inner-loop. I guess in this case, you may also be able to fix things by adjusting your SCHED_FIFO priority down below whatever the priority of the RCU callbacks is currently set to - you basically just want to allow the kernel to run its various tasks at least once in a while.

Comment: Also, our kernel complained quite a bit in dmesg about it - so might be worth it to have a look there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be [realtime throttling](https://lwn.net/Articles/296419/).  When throttling occurs a message appears in the dmesg output.

Once disabled with `echo -1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us`, the `SCHED_FIFO` policy worked as expected.  When a stressor program is introduced on cores 0~2, then `SCHED_FIFO` performs *much* better than `SCHED_OTHER`.

However, there is a better way to avoid realtime throttling without having to disable it for the entire system.  For the program listing in the original question change this code ...

```
auto loop_time_us = duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
while(loop_time_us < 500)
{ 
    loop_time_us = duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}
```

... to this code ...

```
this_thread::sleep_for(400us);
auto loop_time_us = duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
while(loop_time_us < 500)
{
    loop_time_us = duration_cast<microseconds>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}
```

The `this_thread::sleep_for` call will prevent the process from consuming the entire allotted time in `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us` and thus prevent realtime throttling.  Since `sleep_for` is not very precise, you just don't sleep for the full 500 microseconds, and use the `while(loop_time_us < 500)` loop to fill the remaining 100 microseconds with a more precise spin-wait.

This method also prevents the realtime core from turning into a space heater.

Answer (score 0):

Ive a guess here. If you run SCHED_OTHER but set the priority of your process to something other then default, it will promote this process over any other default process. So your task is basicly the single one other all others and therefore hold the cpu even longer.
This is what the documentation reads:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

> SCHED_OTHER: Default Linux time-sharing scheduling
> SCHED_OTHER can be used at only static priority 0 (i.e., threads
> under real-time policies always have priority over SCHED_OTHER
> processes).  SCHED_OTHER is the standard Linux time-sharing
> scheduler that is intended for all threads that do not require
> the special real-time mechanisms.